# ES5 React Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been following this walkthrough: https://simonsmith.io/writing-react-components-as-commonjs-modules/ to separate my React components into separate files. I am using **ES5 JS** and so am using CommonJS and Grunt to convert the JSX to readable JS.

I have 6 components, the top level main component being TodoListApp.jsx and then an index.jsx which has this:

```
    /** @jsx React.DOM */
    var TodoListApp = require('./TodoListApp.jsx');

    ReactDOM.render(
      <TodoListApp url="/api/todos" updateUrl="/api/todos/update" pollInterval={2000}/>,
      document.getElementById('container')
    );
```

At the bottom of each component file I have `module.exports = ...`, for example for TodoListApp.jsx:

```
    module.exports = TodoListApp;
```

When running grunt, it builds an app.built.js file which renders the JSX to JS. This is what my index.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Todo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="./scripts/app.built.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also have a Node.js backend server file in which I can run and go to http://localhost:3000/

I am getting the following error messages in the console:

"Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `TodoListApp`."

"Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `TodoListApp`."

Things I have tried:

- Moving the `ReactDOM.render()` function from index.jsx to the TodoListApp.jsx but get the same error message.
- Using `module.exports = React.createClass({})` instead of using `var TodoListApp = React.createClass({})` with `module.exports` at the bottom of the file and get the same error message.
- I have also tried using:

  ```
  var TodoListApp = require('./TodoListApp.jsx').default;
  ```

  in the index.jsx file as opposed to without `.default` like shown in the first code snippet above. However I then get this error message:

  "Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components)."

  "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined."

Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like an import/export issue. Try debugging the `var TodoListApp = require('./TodoListApp.jsx');` statement, and verify that `TodoListApp` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Did you try = require(...).default; ?

Comment: Yes, I did try that but then got "undefined". Please see above in my original question.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It was because I was requiring the top level component in the other files. Thank you for your help!

Comment: requiring the top level component in other files would not that warning and error.  It would seem that your render method within the TodoListApp.jsx was causing the issue.